# Django listview showing only id and no other field in template

Tags: django, listview, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django. I added a database I created from data I got from a movie database to my Django project. I am using Django's `generic.ListView` to display its fields. However, only the `id` of each movie shows.

Template:

```
<body>

The movies include: <br/>

{% for movie in movies_list %}
    {{ movie.id }} {{ movie.title }} <br/>
    {{ movie.original_language }} <br/>
    {{ movie.overview }}
{% endfor %}

</body>
```

Despite `movie.title`, `movie.original_language`, and `movie.overview` in the code, django-debug-toolbar shows only one query was made when I loaded the page: `SELECT "movies"."id" FROM "movies"`.

models.py in the app directory:

```
from django.db import models

class Movies(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    app_label = "myapp"
    db_table = "movies"
    managed = False
```

views.py in the app directory:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Movies

class MoviesListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movies
    template_name = r'myproject/theme/templates/myapp/myapp.html'
```

I tried adding the following to `class MoviesListView(generic.ListView)` above but it merely doubled the SQL queries for `movie.id`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['movies_list'] = Movies.objects.all()
    return context
```

urls.py in the same directory as settings.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings

from myapp import views as myapp_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', myapp_views.MoviesListView.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
]
```

Here is how I created the table from data from a json file, with the only addition being `id`, which was not provided:

```
create_table_movie = """CREATE TABLE movies (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    adult TEXT,
    original_language TEXT,
    original_title TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    overview TEXT,
    release_date DATE,
    genres TEXT,
    production_countries TEXT,
    videos TEXT,
    images TEXT
    );"""
```

No errors are being reported. What have I missed?

Comment: I might be wrong, but...the model only contains the auto-generated `id` field. Check out [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) to add the fields for the model (or do it yourself, probably for the best). You created the database-table, but not the model.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform I went with Sagar's solution but thought to learn inspectdb too. I tried to follow the documentation you linked and a bit of code in a youtube video I found by typing `django-admin movies --database move_data.sql > legacy_model.py` into shell. But it said: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: I then tried: `python manage.py movies --database movie_data.sql > legacy_model.py` but it said: `django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection movie_data.sql doesn't exist`. I'm not using it right somehow.

Comment: settings.py does contain `USE_I18N = True`.

Comment: I don't have any experience with inspectdb either, but there's always a documentation [django-book](http://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter18.html)

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform Did not know about this one. I've always just used what's on the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) site. This seems slightly clearer, but it doesn't say how to do it from within a project with more than one database in it. I guess for now I can create a new project, use inspectdb, and then transfer the database into my target project. I'll look up more examples when I have more time. Thank you so much for mentioning these though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define All fields in your model which you have mentioned in your sql view.

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    adult = models.TextField()
    original_language = models.TextField()
    original_title = models.TextField()
    title = models.TextField()
    overview = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.DateField()
    genres = models.TextField()
    production_countries = models.TextField()
    videos = models.TextField()
    images = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "myapp"
        db_table = "movies"
        managed = False
```

Comment: this worked. i tried this before. but it kept returning an error so i thought it might not need these since it was displaying id ok anyway. turns out, i got the id and date fields wrong. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any fields in your model, so Django doesn't know about any of the columns from the database. You need a field for each column.

Since this is a table you've created yourself, I don't understand why you've done it manually via SQL. You should create the model in Django first and let Django manage the table via migrations.

Comment: As mentioned above, I did but it didn't work, but it turned out I made a couple of errors. Anyway, I thought to try out what you mentioned too. So I wrote the `def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints)` function into my model router class in router.py and then tried to makemigrations and migrate, but it says there are no changes to apply. But it did create a new database with the name I specified in settings.py. I'm still looking for examples to follow.

Comment: I should probably clarify that I'm trying to add another database to the project, in addition to the default one. This additional database is for a specific app only.